# Material-ui v1 Input focus style override

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to override the styling of the Input component when it is on focus via class name overide.

I have tried the following:

```
const style = theme => ({
  input: {
    width: '20%',
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    border: '1px solid #ced4da',
    fontSize: 20,
    '&:focus': {
      width: '40%',
      borderColor: '#80bdff',
      boxShadow: '0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25)',
    },
  }
});

class test extends Component {

// UI
render() {
    const {classes} = this.props
    return (
        <AppBar position="static">
            <Toolbar>
                <Input className={classes.input} />
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    );
}
}

export default withStyles(style)(test);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to accomplish that is to override the `focused` style exposed by the `Input` component, but using classes instead of class names.

To do so, you should first create a CSS style class specifically for the focused input:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  input: {
    width: '20%',
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    border: '1px solid #ced4da',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  // Separate this part into it's own CSS class
  inputFocused: {
    width: '40%',
    borderColor: '#80bdff',
    boxShadow: '0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25)',
    backgroundColor: "#00FF00",
  },
});
```

Then override the `focused` style on the `Input` like this:

```
<Input
  className={classes.input}
  classes={{ focused: classes.inputFocused}}
/>
```

When you join that all together, a full working example would look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Input from 'material-ui/Input';

const styles = theme => ({
  input: {
    width: '20%',
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    border: '1px solid #ced4da',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  // Separate this part into it's own CSS class
  inputFocused: {
    width: '40%',
    borderColor: '#80bdff',
    boxShadow: '0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0,123,255,.25)',
    backgroundColor: "#00FF00",
  },
});

function Inputs(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Input
        className={classes.input}
        classes={{ focused: classes.inputFocused}}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

Inputs.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Inputs);
```

You can read more about overriding a component's styles with classes [here](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes).

Comment: Silly question, but that is the difference between className and classes used within <Input> ?

Comment: classes can target specific elements used in building the component