# Material-UI.com AutoComplete STYLING

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I have tried many variations of the CSS and it doesn't seem to allow me to change the "focus" state of the outline-color/border-color of the Autocomplete Component. Thanks in advance as I have wasted hours trying to figure out how to change the color! I need it to be green instead of the current blue.

```js
const GreenAutocomplete = withStyles({
    root: {
        '&.MuiAutocomplete-popper': {
            outlineColor: '#68d0af',
            borderColor: '#68d0af',
        },
        '&.MuiAutocomplete-fullWidth': {
            outlineColor: '#68d0af',
            borderColor: '#68d0af',
        },
        '&.MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused': {
            outlineColor: '#68d0af',
            borderColor: '#68d0af',
        },
        '&.MuiAutocomplete-input:focus': {
            outlineColor: '#68d0af',
            borderColor: '#68d0af',
        },
        '&.Mui-focused': {
            outlineColor: '#68d0af',
            borderColor: '#68d0af',
        }
    },
})(Autocomplete);

const GreenTextField = withStyles({
    root: {
        '&.MuiAutocomplete-fullWidth': {
            outlineColor: '#68d0af',
            borderColor: '#68d0af',
        },
        '&.MuiAutocomplete-inputFocused': {
            outlineColor: '#68d0af',
            borderColor: '#68d0af',
        },
        '&.Mui-focused': {
            outlineColor: '#68d0af',
            borderColor: '#68d0af',
        }
    },
})(TextField);

 <GreenAutocomplete
      multiple
      id="tags-filled"
      options={suggestions.map((option) => option.name)}
      onChange={(e,v) => { 
          console.log('authocomplete -> e', e)
          console.log('authocomplete -> v', v) // This is an array
      }}
      // defaultValue={[top100Films[13].title]}
      fullWidth
      freeSolo
      renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
          value.map((option, index) => (
              <Chip variant="outlined" label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
          ))
      }DateTextField
      DOBTextField
      renderInput={(params) => (
          <GreenTextField {...params} variant="outlined" placeholder="Tags" />
      )}
  />
```

[image]

Comment: take look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49054353/12608714

Comment: I tried, but the error message states that the only class i could override is "root". @b3hr4d

Answer (score 0):

I've given up and compromised my design for an easier answer. It doesn't outlines the whole border but at least i can stick to my colors.

```js
const GreenAutocomplete = withStyles({
    root: {
        '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
            borderColor: '#68d0af', // 1fa595
            borderWidth: '2px'
        },
        '& .MuiFilledInput-underline:after': {
            borderColor: '#68d0af', // 1fa595
            borderWidth: '2px'
        }
    },
})(Autocomplete);

const GreenTextField = withStyles({
    root: {
        '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
            borderColor: '#68d0af', // 1fa595
            borderWidth: '2px'
        },
        '& .MuiFilledInput-underline:after': {
            borderColor: '#68d0af', // 1fa595
            borderWidth: '2px'
        }
    }
})(TextField);

<GreenAutocomplete
    multiple
    id="tags-filled"
    options={suggestions.map((option) => option.name)}
    onChange={(e,v) => { 
        console.log('authocomplete -> e', e)
        console.log('authocomplete -> v', v) // This is an array
    }}
    // defaultValue={[top100Films[13].title]}
    fullWidth
    freeSolo
    renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
        value.map((option, index) => (
            <Chip variant="outlined" label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
        ))
    }DateTextField
    DOBTextField
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <GreenTextField {...params} variant="filled" placeholder="Tags" />
    )}
/>
```

[image]